# How to render some parts of the page after the rest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On an article page you can see that article and headline, which loads quickly, but also related articles, which require a lot of database queries to load.

Is it possible to load the article and the headline first, then do the queries and load related articles?

Comment: "but also related articles, which require a lot of database queries to load." you may be having an N+1 problem there.

Comment: Maybe? I'm using a library for that, I don't think I can improve on it.

Comment: add some code of what you have tried please @troricleba